R plot - graphic exceeding margins
I am sure this has been answered somewhere, but I am not able to find a solution that has worked for me. I am trying to plot a graphic using plotTree in the phytools package, but the top and bottom keeps going off the edge of the plot.
I should note that I am using RGui, not R Studio.

I had thought setting margins to par(mar=c(0,0,0,0) would have worked, but it did not. I tried assigning non-zero values to the margins, but that made it worse. I also tried using mai instead of mar, with no improvement. I saw some posts suggesting dev.new(), but that also did not work (and maybe that's because I am not using R Studio?). What alternatives should I attempt?
Update: I have attempted to write to a PDF, changing widths and heights in hopes this could work but it didn’t. Setting the PDF to letter size (portrait or landscape) produced similar results. Interestingly, increasing the size to, for example, 14”x14”, resulted in even more of the graphic getting cut off with whatever else produced very widely spaced apart than it should have been.
Below is some portions of my code, which deal with plotting.
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
#Plot simmap results
plotTree(pruned_tree,type="fan",ftype="i",fsize=0.4,offset=10,lwd=1)
par(fg="transparent",lend=1)
plotTree(pruned_tree,type="fan",ftype="i",fsize=0.4,offset=10,lwd=1,color="white",add=TRUE)
for(i in 1:length(char1.simmap)) plot(char1.simmap[[i]],colors=sapply(cols,make.transparent,alpha=0.01),add=TRUE,lwd=1,type="fan",ftype="i",fsize=0.4,offset=10)
par(fg="black")
#Plot terminal states
pp<-get("last_plot.phylo",envir=.PlotPhyloEnv)
h<-max(nodeHeights(pruned_tree))
obj<-summary(char1.simmap)$ace[1:pruned_tree$Nnode,]
par(lend=3)
for(i in 1:Ntip(pruned_tree)){
cc<-if(pp$xx[i]>0) 0.05 else -0.05 #Adjusts size of terminal state boxes
th<-atan(pp$yy[i]/pp$xx[i])
segments(pp$xx[i],pp$yy[i],pp$xx[i]+cc*cos(th),pp$yy[i]+cc*sin(th),lwd=14,col=cols[Metapleuron.process[pruned_tree$tip.label[i]]])}
#Plot internal pie charts
ii<-order(rowSums(obj^2),decreasing=TRUE)
for(i in ii){
plotrix::floating.pie(pp$xx[i+Ntip(pruned_tree)],pp$yy[i+Ntip(pruned_tree)],radius=if(max(obj[i,])<0.90) 0.03*h else 0.015,x=obj[i,],col=cols)
}
#Plot clade labels
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=which(pruned_tree$tip.label=="Maevius_indecorus_SRR6413622"),orientation="horizontal",cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.85,lab.offset=2.31,lwd=20,col="#66a61e",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Leptocoris_sp_CMF_0673","Maccevethus_errans_CMF_0986")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.85,lab.offset=2.31,lwd=20,col="#bd0026",mark.node=FALSE,stretch=1)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=which(pruned_tree$tip.label=="Dicranocephalus_haoussa_CMF_0718"),orientation="horizontal",cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.85,lab.offset=2.31,lwd=20,col="#7570b3",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Hydarella_chiangdaoensis_CMF_1129","Madura_fuscoclavata_CMF_1078")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.85,lab.offset=2.31,lwd=20,col="#006d2c",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Micrelytra_fossularum_CMF_0910","Stenocoris_tipuloides_CMF_0174")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.85,lab.offset=2.31,lwd=20,col="#6a51a3",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Neomegalotomus_rufipes_CMF_0098_TD60","Heegeria_tangirica_CMF_0961")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.85,lab.offset=2.31,lwd=20,col="#6a51a3",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Gralliclava_horrens_CMF_1165","Coriomeris_denticulatus_CMF_0979")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.85,lab.offset=2.31,lwd=20,col="#006d2c",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Discogaster_dentipes_CMF_1052","Lucullia_flavovittata_CMF_1021")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.85,lab.offset=2.31,lwd=20,col="#006d2c",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Leptocoris_sp_CMF_0673","Jadera_haematoloma_CMF_0281")),ln.offset=1.75,lab.offset=2.06,,lwd=20,col="#fc4e2a",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Liorhyssus_hyalinus_CMF_0898","Maccevethus_errans_CMF_0986")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.75,lab.offset=2.06,lwd=20,col="#e31a1c",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Hydarella_chiangdaoensis_CMF_1129","Madura_fuscoclavata_CMF_1078")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.75,lab.offset=2.06,lwd=20,col="#74c476",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Micrelytra_fossularum_CMF_0910","Stenocoris_tipuloides_CMF_0174")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.75,lab.offset=2.06,lwd=20,col="#9e9ac8",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Neomegalotomus_rufipes_CMF_0098_TD60","Heegeria_tangirica_CMF_0961")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.75,lab.offset=2.06,lwd=20,col="#807dba",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Gralliclava_horrens_CMF_1165","Coriomeris_denticulatus_CMF_0979")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.75,lab.offset=2.06,lwd=20,col="#41ab5d",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Discogaster_dentipes_CMF_1052","Lucullia_flavovittata_CMF_1021")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.75,lab.offset=2.06,lwd=20,col="#238443",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=which(pruned_tree$tip.label=="Liorhyssus_hyalinus_CMF_0898"),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#fed976",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=which(pruned_tree$tip.label=="Harmostes_serratus_CMF_0401"),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#feb24c",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Corizus_hyoscyami_CMF_0973","Rhopalus_parumpunctatus_CMF_0993")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#fed976",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Myrmus_miriformis_CMF_0982","Chorosoma_schillingii_CMF_0933")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#fd8d3c",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Stictopleurus_abutilon_CMF_0983","Maccevethus_errans_CMF_0986")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#fed976",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Mutusca_brevicornis_CMF_0417","Stenocoris_tipuloides_CMF_0174")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#bcbddc",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Micrelytra_fossularum_CMF_0910","Dulichius_trispinosus_CMF_0906")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#dadaeb",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Gralliclava_horrens_CMF_1165","Clavigralla_pusilla_CMF_0952_0960")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#ffffd9",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Vilga_sanctipauli_CMF_1048","Coriomeris_denticulatus_CMF_0979")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#ffffcc",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Discogaster_dentipes_CMF_1052","Mozena_lunata_CMF_0008")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#f7fcb9",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Sephina_geniculata_CMF_0172","Acanthocoris_sordidus_CMF_0276_TD50")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#edf8b1",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Cloresmus_antennatus_CMF_0634","Plectropoda_cruciata_CMF_0037")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#d9f0a3",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Odontocurtus_consociatus_CMF_0694","Latimbus_concolor_CMF_0827")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#c7e9b4",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Galaesus_hasticornis_CMF_0701","Cletus_ochraceus_CMF_0152_TD55")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#addd8e",mark.node=FALSE)
arc.cladelabels(text="",node=findMRCA(pruned_tree, c("Villasitocoris_inconspicuus_CMF_0822","Lucullia_flavovittata_CMF_1021")),cex=0.4,ln.offset=1.65,lab.offset=1.81,lwd=20,col="#78c679",mark.node=FALSE)
legend(x="topleft",levels(Metapleuron.process),pch=22,pt.bg=cols,pt.cex=1.5,bty="n",cex=0.8)


Is it off the page after the initial plotTree call? And which package does plotTree come from?

plotTree is part of the phytools package. The initial plot is not off the page, but that only plots the very center part of the image (the phylogenetic tree and text labels around it).
